# Error when building network dataset in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: network-analyst, arcgis-pro, network-dataset

I have a network dataset with includes roads and turn feature class. 
I updated it once a week. I use ArcGIS Pro to create the network dataset based on a template (but can do manually with network wizard and all errors are the same).

I import turn feature class from the previous network dataset and roads comes from somewhere else.

After build is done, I always get this error for all turns:

> No edge element can be found corresponding to the turn identifier

I don't understand what this error means and how to fix it. 
If I move all turns manually slightly, then build, it works. But it won't work for me as I need automate the process of road network update.

Comment: If you "need automate the process of road network update", have you tried using ArcPy to do that?  If so, please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not seem to be documented for ArcGIS Pro the ArcGIS Desktop documentation on [Common build errors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/common-build-errors.htm) at least acknowledges it as:

> No edge element can be found corresponding to the turn identifier # (where # is a numeric value).

What you are experiencing reminds me of something I encountered in ArcMap, and was only able to resolve with a manual editing step in the middle, at [Using ArcPy to populate turn feature class for Network Analyst by reading edge identifiers from separate table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214719)