# Turn Penalty (Delay) Function for Esri Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, turns

I have a street network for more than 150 intersecting routes which each one of them has its own cost, also changing routes (at junctions between routes) has its cost too.

Creating turn feature class manually is not an appropriate solution bcz of overlapping routes. Imagine bus routes, there are many of them overlapping. The question is how to define turn features for bus stops when a passenger goes for changing routes.

I have tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214985/26738) solution and bcz its about restricted turns not about penalty for turns I couldn't imply it into my data-set.

The Turn Penalty table at junctions is sth in a table like below

```
Orig_Route,Dest_Route,Cost
r(1)      ,r(2)      ,100
r(2)      ,r(2)      ,0
r(1)      ,r(3)      ,75 
...
```

How can I convert this table to Turn Feature Class with Impedance?

I found http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008033 for modifying Global Turn penalties but its about Angle but not about start and end EdgeID. I'm after sth like below code

```
turnPenalty = 0
a = Turn.EdgeId_FROM
b = Turn.EdgeId_TO
If a = b Then
  turnPenalty = 0
elseif a = 1 and b = 2 then
  turnPenalty = 100
elseif ... ' or with Select Case
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Have you tried [Creating a turn feature class in ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-turn-feature-class-in-arccatalog.htm) by following its documentation?

Comment: thanks to your quick reply. I do as you mentioned and edit my question