# Incorporating turn restrictions shapefile into network dataset in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, route, turns

I've started creating routes utilizing Network Analyst with a municipal centerline. I quickly noticed that a few of the routes were incorrect as per the restrictions for turns at given intersections.

I found a municipal turn restrictions shapefile that contains what I need:
[Turn Restrictions](https://www.toronto.ca/city-government/data-research-maps/open-data/open-data-catalogue/#6b9a0b86-ae27-af95-13fc-8e434b2b7bc6)

Here is the geodatabase feature dataset which contains my centerline that I used to initially start creating routes. Elevations, speed, and one-way streets are already incorporated into this file. There is also a blank turn feature class. 
[geodatabase feature dataset](https://nofile.io/f/bwYnGQqEEBC/NA_Network.gdb.7z)

I have not been able to migrate the data from the shapefile into a workable format that the turn feature class can recognize.

Following the steps on this ESRI site:
[Link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/migrating-shapefile-turn-data-to-a-geodatabase.htm)

address what I'm dealing with concerning the shapefile turn data leads me to a dead end, notably that the second step utilizing the "turn table to turn feature class" tool requires ArcVIEW or ArcINFO table format giving me the error: 
[image: Error]

My other option was to try to load the table data from the shapefile into the turn feature class which showed that parts of the data fields match, but the shapefile (whether it is a feature class or not, is missing all the "edge" field parameters while matching with all of its remaining fields which can be seen here:

[image: Missing Data match]

[image: Matching Data]

In this case, is there a step I have missed or is there a workflow within Catalogue to build this edge data from the shapefile data?

Comment: If you are not aware of it, I recommend reviewing https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214719

Comment: Thank you for this link. Unfortunately it is completely beyond my realm of knowledge at this point in time as my coding skills = 0 but I shall read through it and also re-frame this query to be more clear. Thank you for the time you've taken today!

Comment: You may want to vote for this [ArcGIS Idea to provide a Tool for importing turns from table in network dataset](https://community.esri.com/ideas/12717-tool-for-importing-turns-from-table-in-network-dataset).  It took me quite some effort to develop that ArcPy workaround for something that I could imagine many managing road network navigation might want to be able to do.

Comment: I hope my edit is an improvement, and I shall try to wrap my head around your work.

Comment: I do think that this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/using-arcpy-to-populate-turn-feature-class-for-network-analyst-by-reading-edge-I but will hold off on making that conclusion for now to give others a chance to come up with something simpler either here or there.

Comment: So in your opinion, given the format of my shapefile, there is no other way in creating a turn feature class? If I were to attempt your method, where do you suggest I start perusing to make sense of your data and be able to "correctly" match up your parameters to my own data?

Comment: That is my opinion based on my quick review of the latest edits to this question.  I think the place to start to make sense of my code is by running it.  Once you understand how it works on simple test data you will be much better placed to apply the code to your more complex data, or determine whether my quick assessment that it may apply to your situation may be astray.