# Connecting Street lines to Speed Profiles for Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network-dataset

I am creating a network dataset with speed profiles. I have a unique connection between the two where Link_PVID and OLD_FEAT_ID have a unique connection between the two. But it seems that the Patterns needs to have the OBJECTID from the streets as per https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/copying-source-feature-classes.htm

I get the following error for all streets

```
SourceName: Speed_Patterns, ObjectID: 102184814, Network edge not found with positions 0.000000 to 1.000000
SourceName: Speed_Patterns, ObjectID: 102184814, Network edge not found with positions 0.000000 to 1.000000
```

Unfortunately both datasets didn't have a common OBJECTID at any point.

[image]

[image]

I have joined the speed patterns to the streets using the linked field and then got the objectid of the street and pushed that into the EdgeID of the Patterns [3](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/object-id.htm) but this doesn't build the traffic into network.

I have also tried going back to using the tables from the ESRI San Diego Exercise 10 and replacing some sample values but still have the same issues with the error `SourceName: Streets_Patterns, ObjectID: 2, Network edge not found with positions 0.000000 to 1.000000`

I have also tried naming every table to be the same as the exercise.

References

- https://community.esri.com/thread/106547
- https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/common-build-errors.htm
- https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/traffic-historical-10-1-and-later.htm
- [Error when building network dataset in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202436/error-when-building-network-dataset-in-arcgis-pro)

Comment: Are Link_PVID and OLD_FEAT_ID fields that you have added or are either of them system maintained?  By "a unique connection" do you mean that there is a 1:1 relationship between values in the two fields?  What are the precise and detailed steps (all tools, all parameter values) that lead to the error message that you've presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by

1. Join between Speed_Patterns.LinkPVID and Streets.Old_Feat_ID
2. then replacing EdgeFID with the ObjectID from the streets.

This basically ensured that the EdgeFID reflected the ObjectID from the street it referenced.

3.Checked the feature class ID of the original streets table and put this value into the EdgeFCID as per this [esri help.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0047000001rz000000)

4.Made sure the table schema of the Patterns table was exactly as the ESRI sample - critically the EdgeFID and EdgeFCID were Long and not Double

5.Ran the create network from scratch

If any of these weren't exactly followed the historical speed failed.